# Difficulty while making a Table using itemize

Tags: tables, itemize, nicematrix

I am facing a little Problem here. I am trying to make the table show in the picture below [image].

I made this Table in a separate Project and and then pasted its code in my original project.
( I am using a side Project, because the original one has many high-resolution pictures and take a long time to compile ).
However when I pasted it in my original document/ project, this is the result I got.  [image].

Here below is the code I used ( I am new to Latex and am trying to find my way through it

```
newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Entscheidende Vor-und Nachteile bei der Auswahl der Ausrichtung der  Anordnung}
\label{tab: Entscheidende Vor-und Nachteile bei der Auswahl der Ausrichtung der  Anordnung}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
-  & \hspace{1cm} \textbf{Aufrechte Ausrichtung} & 
\hspace{1cm} \textbf{Waagerechte Ausrichtung} \\
\hline
 \textbf{Vorteile} & \tabitem Einfache Positionierung der einzelnen Kom- & \tabitem  Tiefer Schwerpunkt der Versuchsanordnung  \\
 & \hspace{3mm} ponenten im Endbereich & \tabitem  Einfache Montage der gesamten Anordnung \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Nachteile} &  \tabitem  Mechanisch aufwändig   &  \tabitem Aufwendige Positionierung der Komponen- \\
 & \tabitem  Kegelradgetriebe zur Drehmomentübertra- & \hspace{5mm}ten im Endbereich\\
&\hspace{5mm}gung erforderlich&\\ \hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone happen to know why that occured ?
Do you have any hints about how to get the table as shown in the picture 1?
I have Tried itemize, ennumerate but each time there seems to be a problem in in my horizental spacing, because as you see each cell contains a long sentence.
Anything would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- Load the `tabularx` package and its `tabularx` environment to assure that the table will fit inside the width of the text block.
- Load the `enumitem` package and its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros to create a bespoke list-type enviroment (called `\tabitemize` in the code below) for use in table cells.  That way, you won't have to apply line-breaks by hand.

See the code below for some specific ideas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % ragged-right, allow hyphenation
% Create a bespoke itemize-like environment for use in table cells
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt, nosep,
                       before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}},
                       after ={\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightl more open "look"
\caption{Entscheidende Vor-und Nachteile bei der 
         Auswahl der Ausrichtung der  Anordnung}
\label{tab:Entscheidende-Vor-und Nachteile}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|L|L|}
 \hline
 & Aufrechte Ausrichtung & Waagerechte Ausrichtung \\
 \hline
 Vorteile
 & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Einfache Positionierung der einzelnen Komponenten im Endbereich 
   \end{tabitemize}
 & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Tiefer Schwerpunkt der Versuchsanordnung 
   \item Einfache Montage der gesamten Anordnung 
   \end{tabitemize}
 \\
 \hline
 Nachteile
 & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Mechanisch aufwändig   
   \item Kegelradgetriebe zur Drehmomentübertragung erforderlich
   \end{tabitemize}
 & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Aufwendige Positionierung der Komponenten im Endbereich 
   \end{tabitemize}
 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi again ,  I have tried using this option , however , I am still facing an error at \setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt, nosep,
                       before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}},
                       after ={\end{minipage}}}  .    the errors are :  1) unclosed open Group { found at\end{minipage}   2) unexpected close Group } after \begin{minipage 3) unexpected \end{minipage}  4) unexpected colse Group

Comment: @AnisFerjani - Please tell me which version of the `enumitem` package you employ. (This information is contained in the log file.) Also, which TeX distribution to you use, and when did you last update it? The most recent version of `enumitem` is version 3.9, dated 2019/06/20. FWIW, the code I posted above does *not* throw an error on my system (MacTeX2021, w/ all updates applied).

Comment: This is the version am actually using   enumitem 2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists

Comment: appearently the enumitem package changes the some Latex standart behaviour. so there was some error in the code check however the table was  shown and the code did work. I had to disabled the code check this way :  %%begin novalidate
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt, nosep,
                       before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}},
                       after ={\end{minipage}}}
                       %%end novalidate                    %and it worked completely fine , thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This example uses the package `nicematrix`. It offers the command `\Block{}{<content>}` that allows to put content centered in the cell.

It also recognizes the type `X` column, which allows the table to fit the entire text area.

The vertical and horizontal rules of the table are controlled by the directive `hvlines`, in this case, dodging the empty top left corner.

[image: c]

This is the complete code. It will require more then one compilation because it works using PGF/TikZ.

The command `\listfiles` at the beginning will produce a list of all loaded files, to be found at the end of the `.log` file.

Check that you find

```
nicematrix.sty    2021/09/09 v6.2 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ
```

If your version is older please update the package.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

% set list itemize and the X column
\setlist{noitemsep}
\setlist[1]{labelindent=\parindent} 
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering\small
    \caption{Entscheidende Vor-und Nachteile bei der Auswahl der Ausrichtung der  Anordnung}
    \label{tab: Entscheidende Vor-und Nachteile bei der Auswahl der Ausrichtung der  Anordnung}
    \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{NiceTabular}[width=\textwidth]{c L L}[cell-space-limits = 6pt, hvlines,corners]      
                        & \Block{}<\bfseries>{\centering Aufrechte Ausrichtung} &   \Block{}<\bfseries>{\centering Waagerechte Ausrichtung}\\       
        \textbf{Vorteile} 
                        & \Block{}{\begin{itemize} \item Einfache Positionierung der einzelnen Komponenten im Endbereich\end{itemize}}
                        & \Block{}{\begin{itemize}
                                        \item Tiefer Schwerpunkt der Versuchsanordnung 
                                        \item Einfache Montage der gesamten Anordnung 
                                  \end{itemize}}\\      
        \textbf{Nachteile} 
                        & \Block{}{\begin{itemize}
                                        \item  Mechanisch aufwändig 
                                        \item Kegelradgetriebe zur Drehmomentübertragung erforderlich
                                    \end{itemize}}      
                        & \Block{}{\begin{itemize}  \item Aufwendige Positionierung der Komponenten im Endbereich \end{itemize}}\\          
    \end{NiceTabular} 

\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: hi ^^ ,  what do you mean by '' It will require more then one compilation '' ?   I have tried to adopt your suggestion , however , I got 3 Errors .   1) Nicematrix package Error: the option 'width' and ' cell-space-limits' is unknown    2) Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (X): `c' used.  Does this have to do anything with what you meant by 'require a lot of compilation ' ?

Comment: @Anis Ferjani `nicemtrix` works using TiKz. That means that it will be compiled twice. Usually your system does it for you. If not, you do it manually. From the errors you are getting it look you must update, at least the package `nicematrix`. See the use of the command `\listfiles` to check files loaded and their version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick. Use minipage. I have given a example here. One can adjust position of minipage

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{4cm}|c|}\hline
     & b&c \\\hline
      A &\begin{minipage}[t] {0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            
            \item apple
            \item Banana
            \end{itemize} 
        \end{minipage} & One can have some more\\\hline
    \begin{minipage}[m] {0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            
            \item apple
            \item Banana
        \end{itemize} 
    \end{minipage} & This can be done &\begin{minipage}[m] {0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item colour
        \item blue
        \item red
    \end{itemize} 
  \end{minipage}\\\hline
        
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Result of your MWE  doesn't reproduce what the OP is after.  It is also very poor quality ...